# UILocalNotification makes springboard crash

Tags: uilocalnotification, springboard

```
if (application.scheduledLocalNotifications?.count)! > 0 {
        var notificationArray = application.scheduledLocalNotifications!
        let cleanCount = notificationArray.count - 1
        for index in 0 ..< cleanCount {
            let notification = notificationArray[index]
            application.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
            notificationArray.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
```

I create local notifications less than 64 in applicationDidFinishedWithOptions method, and I want to remove these local notifications ,but above code cause crash when my application finished launch

The device console log reports a signal raise.
below is log:

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :  Load 2 pending notification dictionaries

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :  Load pending 2 notifications

DDCharge[5570] : [Bugly] Fatal signal(5) raised.

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :  Remove 1 pending notifications by match

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : checking for prefetched object for key=PendingNotificationRecords bundleID=

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : no object found

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : fetching object for key=PendingNotificationRecords bundleID= checkPrefetch=NO (synchronously)

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : retrieved object from store:

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :  Load 2 pending notification dictionaries

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Did not remove all expected pending notifications

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : checking for prefetched object for key=SBApplicationLocalNotificationsLastFireDate bundleID=

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : found object 505310400

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Load last local notification fire date: 2017-01-05 20:00:00.000 +0800

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :Save pending 2 notifications to application data store

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : checking for prefetched object for key=PendingNotificationRecords bundleID=

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : no object found

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : fetching object for key=PendingNotificationRecords bundleID= checkPrefetch=NO (synchronously)

SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[57] : retrieved object from store:

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Load 2 pending notification dictionaries

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] :Update timers for 2 pending notifications (monitoring: 0)

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Invalidate persistent timer

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Not scheduling local notifications (user notifications: 0, requires local notifications: 0,

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Could not load data at /var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/PushStore/*.pushstore

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Update regions for 2 pending notifications

SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[57] : Saving notification list at /var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/PushStore/*.pushstore with 0 items

```
DDCharge[5570] <Notice>: [Bugly]  Trapped fatal signal 'SIGTRAP(5)'
```

(
    0  DDCharge                       0x000000010018fbb8 0x00000001000ac000 + 932792,

```
1  DDCharge                       0x000000010018f9f8 0x00000001000ac000 + 932344,
2  DDCharge                       0x000000010018bae0 0x00000001000ac000 + 916192,
3  UIKit                          0x000000018a81c6a4 0x000000018a79b000 + 530084,
4  UIKit                          0x000000018aa2ca98 0x000000018a79b000 + 2693784,
5  UIKit                          0x000000018aa32808 0x000000018a79b000 + 2717704,
6  UIKit                          0x000000018aa47104 0x000000018a79b000 + 2801924,
7  UIKit                          0x000000018aa2f7ec 0x000000018a79b000 + 2705388,
8  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001864cb92c 0x0000000186491000 + 239916,
9  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001864cb798 0x0000000186491000 + 239512,
10 FrontBoardServices             0x00000001864cbb40 0x0000000186491000 + 240448,
11 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001848a2b5c 0x00000001847c
```